# How much logic in M, in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a service layer, exposing methods to my MVC 'layer'. Lets say I have a method that:

```
Public List<StateObjects> GetStates()
```

Is it good or poor design to then call that method, from the constructor of my Model object, to maybe build a SelectList of States, for my View? Should the Model have reference to my Service layer, and ALSO, allow my Controllers to have reference to my Service layer? Or should the population of the model's variables be done in the controllers, so have all logic in the controller?

Comment: hmmm, I would think it would be better practice to not tie the Model in with your service layer.  Can't you create view methods that would do the conversion of the List<StateObjects> to the select list?

Comment: Good question. A gotcha for many people, including me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've pointed out there are 2 real options:

- Populate the Model in the controller, using data returned from your business/domain layer
- Populate the Model data inside the model via its constructor, properties or a method.

There is also a third option, which is to have the MC part of MVC in your domain layer. This makes it easier for model population but does blur the line a little a bit (if you are a purist) with what the business layer does. Practically, it doesn't really matter until you're building a giant enterprise model.

My particular preference is to have a static

`public static MyModel FromDomainObject(DomainObject object)`

method on the models. You can then use this in your controller and pass in the domain object in the action to get a Model back, which you pass to your view.

The important part is to make sure the properties in the Model don't populate on demand, and the methods aren't accessible to the view. In reality you or the team will be calling these methods/properties and will know the implications, but it helps to keep the separation of concerns and decrease the coupling.

Comment: can you explain "The important part is to make sure the properties in the Model don't populate on demand". I was going to populate the SelectList objects when the model object is created - i.e. in the Constructor. Is that wrong, or right?

Comment: @Craig that's fine in the constructor, I was talking about getter properties

Answer (score 3):

It is probably not a clear cut answer depending on the size and scope of your application, but when coupled with a service layer I tend to make the "M" of the MVC more of a View Model.

Similar to MVVM, the model becomes a flat object that only contains properties that will be displayed to the View. The controller accesses the service layer, and then uses [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to map the properties of the domain objects to the Model.

What you end up with is thin controllers and thin Models, and most of the logic stays in your service layer. The only time the Model really has any logic is either mapping lists (such as your list of StateObjects) to SelectLists, or other view related functions/calculations. It also allows you to easily map the Model to a JSON object if you are doing any type of asynchronous JavaScript development since the Models are relatively flat.

Having your Model directly reference your service layer means you'd have to pass all of your services into the constructor if you are trying to use some type of dependency injection, which can make instantiation of Models a real pain.

I don't know if that breaks the MVC paradigm, but it has worked well in projects I've done in the past.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is:

**It depends on your application and coding style.**

Many people practice lean models and fat controllers, but coming from a heavy Object Oriented background, it feels more natural to have fat models and lean controllers.  Here's how I think of it:

Models should know about itself. This means functions that depend on models belong in models.

Models should be agnostic to other models. Controllers should be handling model-to-model interactions (and other interactions that don't involve the instance alone).

That way you can have an elegant `instance.function()` and a `controller.staticLikeFunction()`.

IMO this is the most beautiful way to do it int he case that you have a heavily object-oriented application.

If your application doesn't require object-oriented design, then there's no point. In that case, throw everything into the controller and keep your models purely data.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use view model as the model, and keep it lean.   It should only have enough information to communicate to the view and controller, and no more.

Other logic that is necessary for the controller can be contained within classes, and instantiated by the controller.   This keeps your logic loosely coupled, and hence easier to maintain.   You'll be doing yourself a favor.